# How can I cycle through a series of images every few seconds as well as when I click on the screen>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the functionality where if I click on the left or right hand side of my screen I am able to cycle through a series of images.

I would now like to add a timer as well where every few seconds it increments my counter and in turn switches to the next image. I would still like to retain the clicking functionality as well. What is the best way to achieve this?

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/imageclick.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/imgCSS.css">
    </head>
    <body id="imgClickAndChange" style="margin: 0px; background: url('./Images/furnace2.png'); background-size: contain;">
    <div>
       <div id="div-left" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; float: left" onclick="changeImageMinus()">
       </div>
        <div id="div-right" style="height: 100%; width: 50%; float: right" onclick="changeImagePlus()">
       </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var counter = 0;

function changeImageMinus(){
    console.log("minus");
     counter--;
     if(counter == -1) {
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace8.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter = 5;
        console.log(counter);
    }
    if(counter == 0){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace2.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 1){
       $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace3.png)");
       $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 2){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace4.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 3){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace5.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 4){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace6.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 5){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace7.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 6){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace8.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
};

function changeImagePlus(){
    console.log("plus");
    counter++;
    if(counter == 0){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace2.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 1){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace3.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 2){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace4.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 3){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace5.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 4){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace6.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");

        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 5){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace7.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 6){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace8.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        console.log(counter);
    }
    else if(counter == 7){
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace2.png)");
        $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background-size", "contain");
        counter = 0;
        console.log(counter);
    }
};
```

Comment: You should consider encapsulating the CSS properties you're changing into CSS classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setTimeout(function, milliseconds);`

Something like this:

`// call function after 4 seconds
setTimeout( changeImagePlus, 4000 );`

You can read up more about this here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

> The two key methods to use with JavaScript are:
>
> setTimeout(function, milliseconds) Executes a function, after waiting
>   a specified number of milliseconds.
>
> setInterval(function, milliseconds) Same as setTimeout(), but repeats the execution of the function continuously.

You may need to look at canceling it depending on what your page does.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

I ended up using clearInterval() to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

First, keep a count of the current image as an int. You'll also want to save the minimum and maximum counts as an int. Since all the images have the same path except for a number, this will be easy to do. Then make a single function `changeImage(increment)`. It should look like this:

```
function changeImage(increment) {
    imageCount += increment;
    if (imageCount > MAX_COUNT) {
        imageCount = MIN_COUNT;
    else if (imageCount < MIN_COUNT) {
        imageCount = MAX_COUNT;
    }
    renderSlideshowImage(imageCount);
}
```

That will clean up the giant mess of code you've got. `renderSlideshowImage` should just be something like:

```
function renderSlideshowImage(image) {
    $("#imgClickAndChange").css("background", "url(./Images/furnace"+image+".png)");
}
```

Now, as far as the timeout goes, have a click handler and a timeout handler. Each handler function should call `changeImage()` with the appropriate increment. If you like, you can even save the timeout as a variable which will allow you to reset it whenever the button is clicked.

```
myTimer = setTimeout(timeoutHandler, 4000);
clearTimeout(myTimer);
```

One more thing you can do to clean that up is to set the CSS for `#imgClickAndChange` as `background-size: contain` in your CSS file so you don't need to keep setting it, and to save `$('#imgClickAndChange') in a variable (`$changingImage = $('#imgClickAndChange')`) so you don't need to keep setting it.